# developer tools finding executed javascript

Tags: javascript, firebug, visual-web-developer

is there an easy way to find javascript file or function, which is executed for example on click even? Is there a way how to know, that this href link has event and function etc..?

Thank you very much!

Comment: related - [How to find event listeners on a DOM node?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446892/how-to-find-event-listeners-on-a-dom-node)

Comment: Does this **have** to be in firefox? Chome shows you this information quite easily and with no need for additional plugins.

Comment: Yes, using a debugger like Firebug, Chrome Devtools or Dragonfly, you can intercept event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event+2. It does pretty much what you are after.